# How to run Odoo with OCA repositories' modules in Odoo.sh?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo.sh

I am testing Odoo.sh, trying to run an Odoo 15 Enterprise. I read all the documentation and see several webinars about it, but I am not able to run an instance with any OCA module.

To do that, I followed these steps:

1. In the Odoo.sh interface, I created a new branch in the *Development* category, forking from **main** branch (the one in the *Production* category). Note: the **main** branch is the one created by default by Odoo.sh, I didn't make any modification on it and in fact it works OK, I can connect to it.
2. Also in the Odoo.sh interface, I clicked on the button *Submodule* and then on *Run on Odoo.sh*. In the opened pop-up, I added the OCA repository **l10n-spain**, (version 15.0 of course). The repository works perfectly in a local server. In fact you can try with other OCA repository, the result is going to be the same.
3. After doing that, Odoo.sh adds the repo to the project with a new [ADD] commit, and tries to make a build of it. However, the tests always fail.

If I go to the log, first, in the *install.log* section, I can see errors with Pip libraries, so I open a shell and try to fix them, with `pip3 check` and then adjusting the versions of the libraries it complains of.

After that, when I try to connect to the new build, the *odoo.log* starts being filled but also with errors, particularly this one:

```
WARNING xxx odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Tried to poll an undefined table on database xxx.
ERROR xxx odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
    SELECT latest_version
    FROM ir_module_module
    WHERE name='base'
        
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 3:             FROM ir_module_module
                         ^
```

This error uses to appear when you do a wrong installation of Odoo, but the installation is done by Odoo.sh, so... how can I fix this?

Does anyone experienced the same? Any ideas? May be the Python libraries are the problem?

Answer (score 1):

One problem can be that the requirements file brokest the installation. odoo.sh tries to install it automatically, and because odoo.sh is using outdated python modules, the installation usually breaks.

https://github.com/OCA/l10n-spain/blob/15.0/requirements.txt

You can try to copy the required modules directly to your repository.

Comment: +1 I did that before to avoid the *install.log* errors. I opened a shell and installed all those libraries. Then I did `pip check` and followed the instructions to fix the version problems between libraries. Before installing anything, the `install.log` gave this error: `TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`. I still can see it but the log does not show the datetime and it is flashing out all time, so I don't know whether the error is gone with the libraries installation and upgrade or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I managed to connect to the build after open a shell and writing these commands:

- `odoosh-restart http`
- `odoo-update all`

Still didn't check which of them did the trick.